# ConfigParser - Write to existing section

Tags: python, configuration-files

I am a bit stuck at the `ConfigParser`.

I want to add a specific setting to a existing section.

I do:

```
import ConfigParser
Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config
Config.read("/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo")
Config.sections()
Config.set('epel','priority',10)
with open('/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo', 'w') as fout:
```

Then it shows:

```
...
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>
```

Comment: Keep in mind, ConfigParser doesn't keep the original source format or comments.

Comment: Could you explain that please? Thank you very much.

Comment: It strips comments and whitespace while parsing into a local data structure. When writing, it assumes that the order of sections doesn't matter and that "abc = def" is okay. Some programs don't like those rules and stop working. Some users get annoyed when all of their comments are stripped. Try `Config.write(open('/tmp/xyz','w'))` and compare with the original.

Comment: Personally, I don't use ConfigParser when re-writing a system conf file. There are too many things that can go wrong.

Comment: Well, how do you edit them? A user from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352644/add-edit-parameter-in-a-specific-file-section told me that it would be much better to do it with python.

Comment: It can be painful. The [iniparse](http://code.google.com/p/iniparse/) module does a pretty good job.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but to be honest i have no clue how i "install" this now? Sorry but i am completely new to python.. I do my best but it's not that easy :/ Thanks

Comment: There are various ways to install (none guaranteed). Try `sudo easy_install iniparse`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated the question. Would be ncie if you could help me there.

Comment: Okay it looks like it works now. I am right, "wb" keeps the old content and just updates him, while "w" overwrites it?

Comment: unfortunately, no. "wb" skips Microsoft style new-line conversions and is meaningless on linux. You must have trashed the comments in an earlier run. I supose you are doing this for many machines (otherwise, just editing once would do the trick). How about just editing one copy of the epel.repo and copy that everywhere?

Comment: Well after restoring the original file it does indeed not work. It does not change anything. Thats not a option. I need to do it that way (don't ask why ^^). So how can i do that?

Answer (score 6):

Simply,

```
   with open('epel.cfg', 'wb') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples) for examples and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is `Config.write`.

See, for example, the [first example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples)

It should accept a file-like object to write the config data to.  e.g.:

```
with open('new_config.cfg', 'w') as fout:
    Config.write(fout)
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to python and a bit confused now. What's with the `Config.read("")` which i did already? What is the `with open('new_config.cfg', 'w') as fout:` ? Sorry once again for this dumb question. I would appreciate it if you could explain that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Michael -- `Config.read(filename)` populates your ConfigParser instance with data read from the filename.  Then you add some data using `Config.set`.  the `with open...` is the standard python idiom for opening a file to write to.  It's called a context manager.  Googling that will give you lots more information.

Comment: Ah okay. So can i write it directly to the file which i used before? I mean `open('/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo', 'w')`? Or does that not work? I need to write the specific data into the same file.

Comment: @Michael -- Yes, that should work.  Why not make a copy of the original (just in case) and try it out?  :)

Comment: I have updated the question. Unfortunately anything goes wrong. Thanks for the help